# Xamarin for Visual Studio installation failed

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2010, xamarin

I want to install Xamarin for Visual Studio 2010 Professional, I downloaded it from [this](https://www.xamarin.com/download) link but when i try to install it, the installation failed with no errors. Is there any prerequisites to install Xamarin??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Xamarin with VS 2010. This is from [Xamarin System Requirements page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/requirements/):

> Xamarin for Visual Studio supports any Visual Studio 2015 (Community, Professional, and Enterprise) and non-Express editions of Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 and Visual Studio 2012.